# Why can't I use a relationship in a NSManagedObject subclass computed property? (CoreData, swift)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, computed-properties

I'm using CoreData and I have a Book entity and a ReadingSession entity. Each Book has many ReadingSessions.

If I add this computed property to the Book class, it works:

```
var sessions: [ReadingSession] {
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ReadingSession")
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "book = %@", self)
    request.predicate = predicate
    return try! DataController.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [ReadingSession]
}
```

But if I add this one, it doesn't:

```
var sessions: [ReadingSession] {
    return readingSession?.allObjects as! [ReadingSession]
}
```

This last example sometimes returns the correct array and sometimes just returns an empty array.
I tried the same thing with other relationships inside computed properties and the results are the same.

Why is that? Is there a reason why I shouldn't try doing this? Is my first example a valid workaround, or will it cause me problems later on? Should I give up using computed properties for this and just repeat the code when I need it?

Thanks in advance!

Daniel

Comment: Are the relationships bi-directional? How are you updating and saving them?

Comment: @Wain I edited my question with the extra information. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Wain Uhm, I won't be able to try it out now, but I think I found where the problem might be in the Book-User relationship. I messed everything up, my User's "selectedBook" relationship should be To One, not To Many, because there's only one selected book at a time, and then a Book's user shouldn't be assigned when it's created, it's only the User's selectedBook that should be set when a book is selected from a row.

Comment: @Wain Now I still don't know what the problem is in the Book-ReadingSession relationship, but anyway, the answer to my question is that I *should* be able to use relationships in my computed properties, right? So my problem is actually somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, you should. I'm wondering if you're creating duplicate objects somewhere. Have you tried querying for everything in turn to verify what's there?

Comment: @Wain I fixed the problem with the User relationship and now it's all working! The ReadingSessions were returning an empty array sometimes because I was using the User to get to them. Now it's working as expected. Thank you so much for your help. I was so sure the problem was inside the computed properties' code that I wouldn't have looked elsewhere. It's the second time you just ask a couple of simple questions and set me on the right track. And I see you help a lot of others too, so thanks for taking the time. You're awesome!

Comment: Good stuff. Consider adding an answer with details if you think it could help others in future :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, as Wain pointed out in the comments I *should* be able to use relationships inside computed properties, and my problem was actually somewhere else.

If you're interested in the details read the next paragraph, but, long story short, if you're having the same problem you should look into your relationships and make sure they're set properly as To One or To Many. Also check if you're setting all your properties in the right places and only when necessary.

I edited my question to remove lots of unnecessary details and make it more readable, but in the end the problem was that I had a User entity with a selectedBook property which was set when a user selected a row. I had set it up as a To Many relationship, but a user can have only one selectedBook at a time, so it should have been a To One relationship there. Also when I created a book I set user.selectedBook to it, but the selectedBook property should only be set when a user selected a book from a row. So I was setting and trying to access some of my relationships at all the right times. I tried to access a user.selectedBook before a user had even selected a row, for instance, and then it obviously returned nil, which messed up many other computed properties. Now I fixed all that and I'm able to access all my relationships from within computed properties without any issues.